# JS Optimization - constantly setting variables on fast fire events

Tags: javascript, performance, variables, optimization, memory

I am working on a script using Three.js where a lot a variables depend on mouse position. Does it matter if I am constantly setting variables to their same value each time the move event fires, or should I only set a variable when a change is detected?

Let's say I want to set a variable "quadrant" to 1,2,3 or 4 depending upon which part of the screen the mouse is over... should I use this :

```
var quadrant;
function mouseMove(e){
    var mouse;
    mouse.x = e.clientX;
    mouse.y = e.clientY;
    if(mouse.x < window.innerWidth / 2){
          if(mouse.y < window.innerHeight / 2){
              quadrant = 1;
           } else {
              quadrant = 3;
           }
     } else {
          if(mouse.y < window.innerHeight / 2){
              quadrant = 2;
           } else {
              quadrant = 4;
           }
    }
};

window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
```

Which will reset the variable every time the event fires. Or should I only be setting variables when a change is detected, like this :

```
var quadrant;
function mouseMove(e){
    var mouse;
    mouse.x = e.clientX;
    mouse.y = e.clientY;
    if(mouse.x < window.innerWidth / 2){
          if(mouse.y < window.innerHeight / 2){
               if(quadrant != 1){
                     quadrant = 1;
               }
           } else {
               if(quadrant != 3){
                     quadrant = 3;
               };
           }
     } else {
          if(mouse.y < window.innerHeight / 2){
               if(quadrant != 2){
                     quadrant = 2;
               };
           } else {
               if(quadrant != 4){
                     quadrant = 4;
               };
           }
    }
};

window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
```

Does the act of setting a variable to the memory (even if it's to the same value) cost more than it takes to read the extra lines of code necessary to add the conditions? I instinctively do the latter as it seems tidier and like less work at runtime, but I really have no idea how this actually translates to performance. I seem to remember reading that each time a variable is set in js that it's actually creating an instance of itself, which seems like work... but maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: No, not really. These events fire “less fast” than might be believe (less than 100/second) and variable reads and assignments are _very very fast_ (millions per second) - _there is no “relevant cost difference”_ between a read and a write of a variable. Write the code to be clear and correct.

Comment: If anything, I would _expect_ the code with the additional “if” and condition to be “slower” (f.s.v.o. of irrelevance) - it’s simply more code (and handling of such) to traverse. Read. Compare. Conditionally jump.. If really concerned, create some microbenchmarks.. (which have their own share of problems and can mislead some decisions)

Comment: I agree with @user2864740, just set the variable. Whatever source you read that implied that assigning into an existing variable is slow, that was simply mistaken. It doesn't have to create a new instance of anything, it's a very fast operation, especially when you're just assigning a number like this. Of course when considering performance-critical code, it is always wise to benchmark both approaches, but this is a case where the simpler code will definitely be faster.

Comment: Aside: if using ES6+, I suspect that “let quadrant” might enable itself to be implemented slightly more efficiently as it’s a bounded scope variable (not global property on the window object). Even if this is so, the overall performance impact is entirely negligible in context.

Comment: Thank you all so very much for your comments. Had PC problem and haven't been online since I posted yesterday. I understand fully the conditions aren't worth it if working with JS variables, but what about the same question concerning a DOM interaction?! Say I wanted to add a class to a DOM element when the mouse was in a specific quadrant of the screen, in that case should I avoid sending the "addClass" command each time the mouseMove event fires?

Comment: Oh, DOM manipulation is a whole different story: it's _much_ slower than manipulating native JavaScript variables and objects. This is why many JavaScript frameworks use a "[https://www.google.com/search?q=virtual+dom](https://www.google.com/search?q=virtual+dom)" implemented in native JavaScript code. If you were updating DOM elements instead of just a JavaScript variable, then it would be much faster to only make the DOM updates when needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the simpler version is very likely to be faster - and it's easier to read and less error-prone too.

While I've got you, let me suggest a completely different approach: *calculate* the quadrant instead of using a bunch of `if` statements.

```js
// Calculate the quadrant for a given x and y and width and height.
// The quadrants are defined like this:
//
// +---+---+
// | 1 | 2 |
// +---+---+
// | 3 | 4 |
// +---+---+

function getQuadrant( x, y, width, height ) {
    return 1 +
        ( x >= width / 2 ) +
        ( y >= height / 2 ) * 2;
}

console.log( getQuadrant( 25, 25, 100, 100 ) );  // 1
console.log( getQuadrant( 75, 25, 100, 100 ) );  // 2
console.log( getQuadrant( 25, 75, 100, 100 ) );  // 3
console.log( getQuadrant( 75, 75, 100, 100 ) );  // 4
```

This code works because when you use an arithmetic operator on a boolean value, it converts a `false` value to `0` and a `true` value to `1`.

I don't know if this will be faster or slower (you would have to benchmark it to find out) but since you are looking at different approaches to solving the problem, I thought you might find it interesting.

You may wonder "aren't those multiplies and divides slow?" But modern JavaScript engines, like most optimizing compilers, can convert multiplies or divides by a power of 2 into a very fast bit-shifting operation.

Let's take a look at the machine code that V8 generates for the `getQuadrant` function (just showing the core part of the code, not the function setup and teardown).

When we enter this code, the four function parameters are stored in these registers:

`r8` is `x`.
`r11` is `y`.
`rdx` is `width`.
`rdi` is `height`.

And here's the compiled code:

```
; Divide height and width by 2 for the comparisons below
sarl rdi, 1
sarl rdx, 1

; Compare y with half the height and set rcx to 0 or 1
cmpl rdi,r11
setlel cl
movzxbl rcx,rcx

; Compare x with half the width and set rdx to 0 or 1
cmpl rdx,r8
setlel dl
movzxbl rdx,rdx

; Set rdx to the final result, calculated in a single instruction
leal rdx,[rdx+rcx*2+0x1]
```

One likely performance advantage is that this code avoids the branches used by the `if` statements. On modern CPUs, when you can avoid branches, it is often a performance win.

But again, any of these approaches will likely be more than fast enough! Just posting this alternative method in case it is of interest to you.

If you're curious how I got that machine code listing, I created a standalone JavaScript file called `quadrants.js` with this content:

```js
function getQuadrant( x, y, width, height ) {
    return 1 +
        ( x >= width / 2 ) +
        ( y >= height / 2 ) * 2;
}

// We need to actually do something with the result returned by getQuadrant,
// otherwise the JavaScript engine may notice that the result is unused and
// it may skip compiling the function body entirely.

quadrants = [];

for( let i = 0;  i < 1000000;  ++i ) {
    quadrants.push( getQuadrant( 25, 25, 100, 100 ) );
    quadrants.push( getQuadrant( 75, 25, 100, 100 ) );
    quadrants.push( getQuadrant( 25, 75, 100, 100 ) );
    quadrants.push( getQuadrant( 75, 75, 100, 100 ) );
}

// Log the first few results as a sanity check

console.log( quadrants.length );
for( let i = 0;  i < 16;  ++i ) {
    console.log( quadrants[i] );
}
```

Then I ran it with this command:

`node --print-opt-code --code-comments quadrants.js >code.txt`

And then I looked through the generated `code.txt` file to find the code for the `getQuadrant` function.

Comment: Wow this is an amazing answer!! Tyvvvvm for taking the time!!! That boolean tip is really useful, I'm sure I'll be able to use that in my code from now on. I repeated what you said to get the code listing, but didn't understand much of what was in the code.txt. For me the results were divided into two parts, just the function (size=316) and then the whole code (size=1700). Can I use those size measures to gauge/compare how optimized my code is? I'm assuming smaller is better. I'm curious though, why though is the simpler version less error prone?

Comment: I actually feel a little bad as the quadrants thing was just an example to illustrate the problem... I'm actually using three.js and raycaster to determine what objects I am over in the scene, finding the exact object with a for loop on the name.. (obj0, obj1, obj2 etc.) and the quadrant variable then changes the properties of animations. But I'm also using it to add classes for hover effects on my cursor - which I guess I should probably NOT be doing every time the mousemove event fires? I am a little concerned about IF statements now - I use a lot of them to determine my animations.

Comment: Don't feel bad, I had fun writing this up. :-) About the `if` statements, don't panic! As noted in my other comment on your question, if you can use an `if` statement to avoid adding or removing a classname on a DOM element except when really needed, that's a big win. The DOM is slow compared with native JS code.

Comment: _"I'm curious though, why though is the simpler version less error prone?"_ I didn't mean that the code would more or less error prone once it was written and tested, only that simpler code is easier to get correct in the first place.

Comment: _"Can I use those size measures to gauge/compare how optimized my code is?"_ I wouldn't use that directly. After all, a direct DOM update on every `mousemove` would be less code than wrapping it in an `if` test to avoid the update when not necessary. But the `if` test to avoid needless updates would speed up the code considerably.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, all this has been really helpful. I'm completely self-taught in js (and have learnt most of what I know from examples on this site)... but as a result I am worried that the way I code is very messy and poorly optimized. Especially as usually when I start out I have no idea how to achieve the results I want, i just learn + build up functionality bit by bit until I get what I want... but as a result you get one thing on top of another and the result can be a little chaotic - I imagine a good coder could achieve the same results with half the line of code.

Comment: It's also difficult to teach yourself certain techniques... if you're not aware of their existence or importance you don't know to google them! I'm following a little course atm called "JS - Understanding the weird parts" in the hope it will improve my understanding all round - well I'm trying to, but I keep getting distracted by working on other things!! I'm trying to build myself a new website using a lot of Three.js atm - I've some exp with 3d modeling and environment building so would like to use that on my web page. Thanks again for all the great info!

Answer (score 1):

Performance wise, they should be very similar. However it really depends on what happens after setting the variable. Are you going to call a function that do hefty work each time? Then you're better of using the second one.

You shouldn't bother yourself with micro-optimizations, A couple milliseconds delay won't really affect your application.

Also if you need to see for yourself here's some benchmark code to run (It won't be that accurate though). It shows the average time in seconds for running each function 1k times

```js
let sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0, quadrant;
for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++){

    let obj = calculate(1000);
    sum1 += obj.t1;
    sum2 += obj.t2;

}
console.log("avg for first: ", sum1 / 1000);
console.log("avg for second: ", sum2 / 1000);

function calculate(numIterations){
    
    //first function
    let start = Date.now();
    for(let i = 0; i < numIterations; i++){
        mouseMove(generateEventObject());
    }
    let t1 = (Date.now() - start) / 1000; 
    //second function
    start = Date.now();
    for(let i = 0; i < numIterations; i++){
        mouseMove2(generateEventObject());
    }
    let t2 = (Date.now() - start) / 1000; 
    return {t1, t2}
}

function generateRandom(max) {
    return Math.random() * max;
}

function generateEventObject() {
    return {
        clientX: generateRandom(window.innerWidth),
        clientY: generateRandom(window.innerHeight)
    }
}

function mouseMove(e){
    var mouse = {};
    mouse.x = e.clientX;
    mouse.y = e.clientY;
    if(mouse.x < window.innerWidth / 2){
          if(mouse.y < window.innerHeight / 2){
              quadrant = 1;
           } else {
              quadrant = 3;
           }
     } else {
          if(mouse.y < window.innerHeight / 2){
              quadrant = 2;
           } else {
              quadrant = 4;
           }
    }
};

function mouseMove2(e){
    var mouse = {};
    mouse.x = e.clientX;
    mouse.y = e.clientY;
    if(mouse.x < window.innerWidth / 2){
          if(mouse.y < window.innerHeight / 2){
               if(quadrant != 1){
                     quadrant = 1;
               }
           } else {
               if(quadrant != 3){
                     quadrant = 3;
               };
           }
     } else {
          if(mouse.y < window.innerHeight / 2){
               if(quadrant != 2){
                     quadrant = 2;
               };
           } else {
               if(quadrant != 4){
                     quadrant = 4;
               };
           }
    }
};
```

Comment: Oh wow. What a great idea!! I've already copied this code into a little folder that I'll keep for testing, it's a great idea for comparing functions... thank you so much! I appreciate it may not be 100% accurate but it still gives a basic benchmark. I'm using Three.js and a raycaster to test what objects the mouse is over, and as I have a custom cursor I am using it to add and remove classes for hover effects - I guess those interactions I should limit though, np? And not have my code trying to add or remove the same class 100 times per second?

Comment: P.S Sry I didn't reply sooner, had lil problem with PC after posting and it turned into this whole "thing"... lol (PC is a lot cleaner now though xD)

Comment: lol :'D. Well, DOM manipulation costly be nature so I guess you should limit that. Also take a look at this it might be helpful: [DOM Performance Case study](https://areknawo.com/dom-performance-case-study/), it also explains the rendering pipeline which is going to be helpful I guess :D

Comment: That's a really useful article... I am going to try and implement some of the suggestions, although I'm not sure my understanding of code execution order is entirely sufficient to do a great job though. I'm using three.js and requestAnimationFrame to animate... but I think I can save all the formatting info in scoped variables and only update the Dom objects right at the end of each frame, rather than throughout the frame as each obj position etc is calculated. Thanks for the link!!